# Add list values together in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['9,7,4', '10,5,6,5,5', '10,8,5,3,0', '8,4,2']
```

How can i convert the numbers to ints and add the individual string values together?

So the desired out put would be

```
['20','31','26','14']
```

Comment: loop through the list, split the strings by commas, convert to ints (`int(string)`) and sum the resultant list.

Comment: You should do this, if I understood: 1) iterate through the strings, 2) split the strings on commas 3) convert split strings to integers, 4) merge the result into one list. Which part do you have a question about?

Comment: So, the true question is: how to find the sum of `'9,7,4'`? (If you can do that, you can do the rest.) `split` the string, convert each fragment to an `int`, apply  `sum`, convert back to a `str`ing.

Comment: Hey, i updated my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Use `map` to convert the splitted (using `,` as the delimiter) string values into `int` followed by a list comprehension to get the sum

```
input_list = ['9,7,4', '10,5,6,5,5', '10,8,5,3,0', '8,4,2']
output = [str(sum(map(int, x.split(',')))) for x in input_list]
print (output)
```

**Output**

```
['20', '31', '26', '14']
```

I edited after seeing your desired output as strings

Comment: using `map`  inside a list comprehension is quite expensive. I guess you ould use vectorized functions after splitting.

Comment: `[str(sum(np.array(i.split(","),dtype="i"))) for i in input_list]`

Answer (score 2):

```
[sum(map(int, group.split(','))) for group in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone mentioned `eval`, so I think you should take this a step further with a safe-eval alternative:

```
>>> import ast
>>> [ast.literal_eval(v.replace(',', '+')) for v in lst]
>>> [20, 31, 26, 14]
```

One thing I like about this answer is that it is purely a non-functional approach (no `map` inside a list comprehension, which is fine but I don't really believe in mixing paradigms).

Obviously this will only work if you have numbers separated by a single comma, without any leading or trailing characters and invalid arithmetic expressions.

I leave the conversion to string as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

If all strings are in this format you can try to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function - this will convert numbers into tuples from which you can count sum.

```
>>> l = ['9,7,4', '10,5,6,5,5', '10,8,5,3,0', '8,4,2']
>>> sums = [sum(numbers) for numbers in map(eval, l)]
>>> sums
[20, 31, 26, 14]
```

If you want output list to contain strings these values can be easily mapped:

```
[str(value) for value in sums]
# or
map(str, sums)
```